# Extract the rows from the text + python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract entire rows from a text file, but its not working as expected.

Sample Text file content:

```
data = """Add TTFF LEVERERGE 30 mp -5%
Some Text, Some Text
5882950 Abc Lahd
Pos Sequence Batch datax datay dataz dataa datab
1 00061680 904834 20.35 REV 177,650 5329,50
Bundled 2-rev 42al/xyz
Neon Classic Unit 1300 abc \ 1638\48
2 00012815 55244 815 FWD 164,720 18448,64
UnBundled 2-pag
Mathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb
150st/xyz 20 abc/xyz
3 90072815 65944 212 KRT 164,720 18448,64
UnBundled 2-pag
Mathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb
150st/bunt 20 bunt/bal
Some Valid Text
Some More Valid Text Some More Valid Text"""
```

I want all three rows in a list format to extract particular values from them.

Logic is:

1. Stop the extraction before we start the new row
2. Each Row strats with a sequencedigit (1, 2, 3, ..., 99. etc)
3. Consider the end of last row which ends with "Some Valid Text"

(As first 2 steps are not working, so not considered regex for #3 this step in re.findall)

```
$re.findall(r'(^\d{1,2}\s.*?\n^\d)', data, re.DOTALL|re.M)

['1 00061680 904834 20.35 REV 177,650 5329,50\nBundled 2-rev 42al/xyz\nNeon Classic Unit 1300 abc \\ 1638\x048\n2',
 '3 90072815 65944 212 KRT 164,720 18448,64\nUnBundled 2-pag\nMathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb\n1']
```

Expected Result is:

```
['1 00061680 904834 20.35 REV 177,650 5329,50\nBundled 2-rev 42al/xyz\nNeon Classic Unit 1300 abc \\ 1638\x048\n',
'2 00012815 55244 815 FWD 164,720 18448,64\n    UnBundled 2-pag\n    Mathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb\n    150st/xyz 20 abc/xyz',
'3 90072815 65944 212 KRT 164,720 18448,64\nUnBundled 2-pag\nMathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb\n150st/bunt 20 bunt/bal']
```

Any guidance/help to extract the rows from the text?

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - edited, thanks for suggestion

Comment: ok, what if rows start with unordered numbers like `2 text ...., 7 text .... , 10 text, 3 text ...` not `1 .... 2 ... 3 ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `re.findall()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
rows = re.findall(r'(^\d{1,2} .+?)(?=\n(?:\d+ |Some Valid Tex))', data, re.DOTALL | re.M)
print(rows)
```

The output:

```
['1 00061680 904834 20.35 REV 177,650 5329,50\nBundled 2-rev 42al/xyz\nNeon Classic Unit 1300 abc \\ 1638\x048', '2 00012815 55244 815 FWD 164,720 18448,64\nUnBundled 2-pag\nMathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb\n150st/xyz 20 abc/xyz', '3 90072815 65944 212 KRT 164,720 18448,64\nUnBundled 2-pag\nMathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb\n150st/bunt 20 bunt/bal']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a regex that has to "count up" as part of a pattern, I would not go for a regex, you should use a parser instead - regex is for regular patterns, not for counting (although some ppl here create regexes I thought not possible).

This is a simple straightforward -**non regex**- approach. The last item has to be cleaned up as you did not provide a significat "STOP HERE" marker. I highly doubt `' Some Valid Text Some More Valid Text Some More Valid Text']'` will be part of your text so that does not qualify for "stopping".

The output also does not contain terminating `'\n'` - I used them to split the lines into -well- lines. You could add a `'\n'` when `join()`ing the `part`s if you *really* need them:

```
data = """Add TTFF LEVERERGE 30 mp -5%
Some Text, Some Text
5882950 Abc Lahd
Pos Sequence Batch datax datay dataz dataa datab
1 00061680 904834 20.35 REV 177,650 5329,50
Bundled 2-rev 42al/xyz
Neon Classic Unit 1300 abc \ 1638\48
2 00012815 55244 815 FWD 164,720 18448,64
UnBundled 2-pag
Mathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb
150st/xyz 20 abc/xyz
3 90072815 65944 212 KRT 164,720 18448,64
UnBundled 2-pag
Mathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb
150st/bunt 20 bunt/bal
Some Valid Text
Some More Valid Text Some More Valid Text"""

rdata = data.split('\n')
skipprows = rdata.index('Pos Sequence Batch datax datay dataz dataa datab')
lines = rdata[skipprows + 1:]

i = 1       # looking for this + space at string start to see when 1 line id done
part = []   # collects parts that belong to one line
result = [] # holds the joined lines from part
for li in lines:
    if li.startswith(f'{i} '):            # look for linenr + space
        if part:                          # do not add empty parts
            result.append(' '.join(part)) # add joined if something in it
        part = [li]                       # start with current li for next parts
        i += 1                            # increase so we look for next one
    else:
        part.append(li)

if part:                                  # add last part if not empty
    result.append(' '.join(part))

print(result)                             # print all
```

Output:

```
['1 00061680 904834 20.35 REV 177,650 5329,50 Bundled 2-rev 42al/xyz Neon Classic Unit 1300 abc \\ 1638\x048', 
 '2 00012815 55244 815 FWD 164,720 18448,64 UnBundled 2-pag Mathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb 150st/xyz 20 abc/xyz', 
 '3 90072815 65944 212 KRT 164,720 18448,64 UnBundled 2-pag Mathrine Classic straight Tilt 2 xyz / 23,2x23gb 150st/bunt 20 bunt/bal Some Valid Text Some More Valid Text Some More Valid Text']
```

---

**caveat**: If your lines happen to be like:

```
1 Some thing to eat
and some more data of it, containing
2 packs each
2 Some other thing to eat to get more muscles
and even more text containing 
3 things that make you BIGGGER
3 Last text ....
```

the parsing will get wonky and you wont get the correct data you are after.